# Is there an advantage of using Random() over Random.secure() if a cryptographically strong random number isn't required?

Tags: dart, random

Dart has two different ways of generating random numbers. `Random()` and `Random.secure()`, where the former is pseudo random. With only this information, it seems obvious that `Random.secure()` should be used all the time to be sure that the number generated is completely random.

However, since both ways of generating a number exists, I suspect that there are advantages of using `Random()`. Is that correct, and what are those advantages in that case?

Comment: Not sure about Dart, but usually random number generation can be much faster if it needn't be cryptographically strong.  Try timing both ways.

Comment: Pseudo-random numbers are faster to generate and can be reproduced if you know the seed.

Comment: I have not study all implementations but on most platforms, `Random.secure` will get its numbers from the OS kernel, so it is a lot slower compared to a normal `Random()` generator which gets a seed and then generates an endless stream of random numbers based on that.

Comment: @jamesdlin worth noting that the reproducibility can be essential for debugging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some tests, and, like people commented, `Random()` is indeed faster.

When generating 100000 random integers between 0 and 100, `Random()` is 334 ms faster, and the average time to get one random number was 0.03 ms compared to 3.37 ms for `Random.secure()`. So unless you are generating a lot of numbers or the task you are doing requires a high speed, that difference probably won't matter.

Another difference I found comes from the documentation:

```dart
/// If the program cannot provide a cryptographically secure
/// source of random numbers, it throws an [UnsupportedError].
```

This means that `Random.secure()` might fail on some platforms, while `Random()` does not. So unless a secure number is required, `Random()` is probably preferred, since you don't have to care about error handling.

Here is the code I wrote to test the speed. There is probably some overhead from the for loops, but since I'm doing a comparison, that does not affect the difference.

```dart
import 'dart:math';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  var psuedoRandom = Random();
  var secureRandom = Random.secure();

  var length = 100000;

  var startTime = DateTime.now();
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    psuedoRandom.nextInt(100);
  }
  var psuedoDuration = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch - startTime.microsecondsSinceEpoch;
  var psuedoAverage = psuedoDuration / length;

  startTime = DateTime.now();
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    secureRandom.nextInt(100);
  }
  var secureDuration = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch - startTime.microsecondsSinceEpoch;
  var secureAverage = secureDuration / length;

  var psuedoAdvantage = secureDuration - psuedoDuration;

  print('length: $length\n');

  print('psuedo duration: $psuedoDuration');
  print('psuedo average duration: $psuedoAverage\n');

  print('secure duration: $secureDuration');
  print('secure average duration: $secureAverage\n');

  print('Advantage for psuedo: $psuedoAdvantage');
}
```